# Python Apache Beam Dataflow runner

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I created a very simple dataflow pipeline using Apache Beam in the python SDK.  When I use DirectRunner, the flow executes correctly without error.  However, when I use the DataflowRunner, I get the following exception:

```
  File "dataflow/dataflow.py", line 111, in <module>
    run()
  File "dataflow/dataflow.py", line 102, in run
    | 'WriteVideoData' >> WriteToText(args.output)
  File "/usr/src/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 335, in __exit__
    self.run().wait_until_finish()
  File "/usr/src/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 328, in run
    return self.runner.run(self)
  File "/usr/src/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow_runner.py", line 264, in run
    super(DataflowRunner, self).run(pipeline)
  File "/usr/src/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py", line 133, in run
    pipeline.visit(RunVisitor(self))
  File "/usr/src/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 353, in visit
    self._root_transform().visit(visitor, self, visited)
  File "/usr/src/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 685, in visit
    part.visit(visitor, pipeline, visited)
  File "/usr/src/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 685, in visit
    part.visit(visitor, pipeline, visited)
  File "/usr/src/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 685, in visit
    part.visit(visitor, pipeline, visited)
  File "/usr/src/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 685, in visit
    part.visit(visitor, pipeline, visited)
  File "/usr/src/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 688, in visit
    visitor.visit_transform(self)
  File "/usr/src/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py", line 128, in visit_transform
    self.runner.run_transform(transform_node)
  File "/usr/src/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py", line 171, in run_transform
    return m(transform_node)
  File "/usr/src/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow_runner.py", line 497, in run_ParDo
    input_step = self._cache.get_pvalue(transform_node.inputs[0])
  File "/usr/src/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py", line 249, in get_pvalue
    value_with_refcount = self._cache[self.key(pvalue)]
KeyError: ('WriteVideoData/Write/WriteImpl/DoOnce/Decode Values', None)
```

My pipeline is currently very simple since I'm just trying to get things up and running, and looks like this:

:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function

import argparse
import logging
import sys
import json
import time

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.metrics.metric import Metrics
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import GoogleCloudOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import StandardOptions
from apache_beam.io import WriteToText
from boto.s3 import connect_to_region
...
    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        events = (
            p
            | 'ReadPubSub' >> beam.io.gcp.pubsub.ReadStringsFromPubSub(args.topic)
            | 'FetchVideoData' >> beam.ParDo(DownloadVideoData())
            | 'AddEventTimestamps' >> beam.Map(lambda elem: beam.window.TimestampedValue(elem, elem['timestamp']))
            | 'WriteVideoData' >> WriteToText(args.output)
        )
```

Any help/advice would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Edit: Removed my broken "workaround".

Comment: Your workaround will not work, because you are outside of the `with Pipeline` block.
I'm looking at why you're getting that error.

Comment: Can you share your imports, and which Beam version you are using?

Comment: v2.1.1, and my imports have been updated.

Comment: What's in your args.output? Is it local file path?

Comment: @MarcinZablocki in this case, args.output refers to a google storage path, it's in the form gs://mybucketname/path.

Comment: have you tried upgrading to a later version? This error is pretty strange, but it should hopefully resolve in newer versions..

Comment: That's the latest version on pypi.  If I upgrade to a version not from pypi, it fails when gcs is staging the SDK tarball.  Namely:

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apache-beam==2.3.0.dev0 (from versions: 0.6.0, 2.0.0, 2.1.0, 2.1.1)
No matching distribution found for apache-beam==2.3.0.dev0

Comment: ugh sorry about that...

Comment: I checked with the Python team. Currently WriteToText is not supported for streaming pipeline. I'm not sure if this error occurs for that reason, but you won't be able to run a pipeline with PubSub and WriteToText.

Comment: Thanks Pablo for your help, I'll work around it!